# running protractor on Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am having issues running protractor on Mac OS X El Capitan. I have installed selenium webdriver.

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

And I have already installed protractor globally and locally:

`sudo npm install -g protractor`

`sudo npm install protractor`

Selenium server is running already:

`webdriver-manager start`

When I run "protractor conf.js" I get tests failure.

Output:

Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

1) segment page encountered a declaration exception
 Message:
   TypeError: protractor.getInstance is not a function 
   TypeError: browser.getInstance is not a function

2) page encountered a declaration exception
   Message:
     TypeError: by.selectedOption is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Girish suggested, I figured out that protractor.getInstance(), by.selectedOptions, findElement(), findElements() etc are no longer supported. I changed those occurrences with browser.getInstance(), by.model, element() and all() respectively. Now all of the tests are working. Thanks guys.

Comment: `browser.getInstance is not a function` :(

Comment: use browser.driver